Uniform bound on exponential approximation
I am interested in computing some $\alpha, \beta, N >0$ such that the following holds whenever $n \ge N$:
$$ \max_{0 \le t \le n} \bigg| \bigg( 1 - \frac tn \bigg)^n - e^{-t} \bigg| \le \alpha \cdot n^{-\beta}
 $$
Remark.
This should be well-known / hiding in some real analysis textbook, although it's quite pesky. One key challenge above is to produce a uniform approximation over $t \in [0,n]$. Computational evidence suggests that such $\alpha, \beta, N$ above exist.

Let $x=1-t/n.$ The problem is equivalent to determining the maximal value of  the function
$$f(x):= e^{n(x-1)}-x^n,\quad 0\le x\le 1$$ The function $f(x)$ is nonnegative as
$g(x):=e^{x-1}-x\ge 0.$ Indeed $g'(x)=e^{x-1}-1\le 0.$ Hence $g$ is decreasing. Thus its minimal value is attained at $x=1$ which implies  $g(x)\ge g(1)=0.$ The maximal value of $f$ is attained at some point $x_0$ such that
$$0=f'(x_0)=n[e^{n(x_0-1)}-x_0^{n-1}]$$
i.e. $e^{n(x_0-1)}=x_0^{n-1}.$ Then
$$f(x_0) =e^{n(x_0-1)}-x_0^{n-1}+(1-x_0)x_0^{n-1}=(1-x_0)x_0^{n-1}$$
Observe that the maximal value of the function $h(x)=(1-x)x^{n-1}$ on $[0,1]$ is attained at ${n-1\over n}.$ Moreover $h({n-1\over n})={1\over n}({n-1\over n})^{n-1}\le {1\over n}.$
Summarizing $0\le f(x)\le {1\over n},$ i.e. $\beta =\alpha=1.$ The constant $\alpha$ can be improved  as by the Bernoulli inequality we have $$\left (1+{1\over n-1}\right )^{n-1}\ge 2$$ Thus
$$\left ({n-1\over n}\right)^{n-1}=\left [\left (1+{1\over n-1}\right )^{n-1}\right ]^{-1}\le {1\over 2}$$
I believe the constant $\beta$ cannot be improved as $f({n-1\over n})$ should behave asymptotically as a constant multiple of $ {1\over n}.$

That's lovely, thank you!

By diffrentiating the lhs arguement $\bigg( 1 - \frac tn \bigg)^n - e^{-t}$ with respect to 't' , we have $\bigg( 1 - \frac tn \bigg)^{n-1} - e^{-t} = 0$ (call this the differentiated equation) for it to attain its maximum magnitude.
As $n\to \infty$ , this diffrentiated expression becomes 0 at $t\to 2$ (thus $e^{-2} = (1-\frac2n)^{n-1}$ at large n,, we will use this ahead)
So the original expression has $\bigg| \bigg( 1 - \frac 2n \bigg)^n - e^{-2} \bigg|$ on the lhs.
And as for this, we can also substitute $$\bigg( 1 - \frac 2n \bigg)^n = \bigg( 1 - \frac 2n \bigg)^{n-1} \cdot \bigg( 1 - \frac 2n \bigg)$$ and putting the value of $\bigg( 1 - \frac 2n \bigg)^{n-1}$ as $e^{-2}$
we finally arrive to the equation: $$ e^{-2} - e^{-2}\cdot\bigg( 1 - \frac 2n \bigg) \le \alpha\cdot n^{\beta} $$
Which finally gives us $$ \frac 2n \cdot e^{-2} \le \alpha\cdot n^{\beta} $$
Thus $\alpha = 2\cdot e^{-2}$ and $\beta = -1 $ for sufficiently large N,
but we can take any smaller N which will lead to other values of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.
Pointing any mistakes or clarifying anything which remains unclear are highly appereciated.

Welcome to Maths SE! I think your differentiation in the beginning is wrong.

I differentiated the whole and multiplied the eqn with 1 on both sides. I dont know where it is wrong

That's because you didn't use the rules of differentiating a composition of functions: $(f(g(x)))' = g'(x) \cdot f'(g(x))$.

Could you point out where i didnt use

Regarding the best $\alpha$ and $\beta$:
Let
$$f(t, n) := \mathrm{e}^{-t} - (1 - t/n)^n.$$
We have $f(1, n) \sim \frac{\mathrm{e}^{-1}}{2n}$ as $n\to \infty$.
Thus, $\beta \le 1$.
We claim that the best constants are $\alpha = \mathrm{e}^{-1}$, $\beta = 1$ in the sense that, for all $n \ge 0$,
$$\max_{0 \le t \le n} \bigg| \bigg( 1 - \frac tn \bigg)^n - e^{-t} \bigg| \le \alpha \cdot n^{-\beta}.$$
(1) Prove that $\beta = 1$ is the best.
Let us prove that, for all $0 \le t \le n$,
$$\mathrm{e}^{-t} - (1 - t/n)^n \le \mathrm{e}^{-1} n^{-1}. \tag{1}$$
If $n \le \mathrm{e}^{t-1}$, then
$\mathrm{e}^{-t} \le \mathrm{e}^{-1}n^{-1}$, and (1) is true.
If $n > \mathrm{e}^{t-1}$, it suffices to prove that
$$g(t) := n\ln(1 - t/n) - \ln(\mathrm{e}^{-t} - \mathrm{e}^{-1} n^{-1}) \ge 0.$$
We have
$$g'(t) = \frac{n\mathrm{e}^t}{(n - t)(n - \mathrm{e}^{t-1})}(\mathrm{e}^{-1} - t\mathrm{e}^t)\ge 0$$
where we use $\mathrm{e}^{t-1}\ge t$
and $\mathrm{e}^{-1} \ge t\mathrm{e}^t$ for all $t \ge 0$. Also, we have $g(0) = -\ln(1 - \mathrm{e}^{-1}n^{-1}) \ge 0$.
Thus, $g(t) \ge 0$ for all $0 \le t \le n$.
(2) Prove that $\alpha = \mathrm{e}^{-1}$ is the bets.
Let
$$h(t, n) := n \left(\mathrm{e}^{-t} - (1 - t/n)^n\right).$$
We have $h(1,1) = \mathrm{e}^{-1}$.
We are done.
